# Spring core application shows" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/KotlinDetector"

Tags: java, spring

I am creating a basic spring hibernate application. I follow this link : https://www.javatpoint.com/hibernate-and-spring-integration .I got an error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/KotlinDetector"`.I am new to spring. So please help me to correct this error.

**INSERT.JAVA**

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;


public class Insert {
public  static void main(String...args) {
    ApplicationContext ac=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("ac.xml");
    EmpDao d=(EmpDao)ac.getBean("d");
    Employee e=new Employee();
    e.setId(101);
    e.setName("upkar");
    e.setSalary(15000);
    d.saveEmployee(e);
}
}
```

**ac.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">  

<bean id="datasource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicsDataSource" >
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
<property name="mappingResources">
<list>
<value>employee.hbm.xml</value>
</list>
</property>
<property name="hibernateProperties">
<props>
<prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.show.sql">true</prop>
</props>
</property>
</bean>
<bean id="template" class=" org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate">
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="d" class="com.upkar">
<property  name="template" ref="template"></property></bean>
 </beans>
```

Comment: Seems like Spring version issue. Which spring version are you using? Specify all the jar versions or equivalent pom if using maven.

Comment: <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.17.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>